# Aha! It's the splash banner. Should that be changed to match the FAQ?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

The FAQ now says *"Photography - Stack Exchange is for professional, enthusiast and amateur photographers."*

The splash bar when a new user first visits the site, however, says *"Welcome to Q&A for professional photographers, photo editors, and serious enthusiasts — check out the FAQ!"*

This has the old wording about "photo editors", and restricts the focus to professionals and *serious* enthusiasts.

Is it desirable for this first message to be less inclusive than the site description in the FAQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is stored at the network level and appears in http://stackexchange.com/sites among other places.

I modified it to be in sync with the faq per your request.

Comment: Awesome; thanks.